# Restarting Hudson on Windows

Tags: windows, hudson, restart, jenkins

I've been having an issue with Hudson on windows.

Whenever I update Hudson or a plugin I get the option to restart when no jobs are running.
If I click this button Hudson hangs and doesn't restart. I've tried restarting the Hudson service but this doesn't help, so end up having to reboot the box to bring Hudson back online.

I've just updated to the most recent version, but didn't click the restart button and it's now vanished.

Is there a correct way to restart Hudson on windows?

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a this problem once in a while too. For some reason the Hudson server does not shut down completely and the server that starts up, can not use the port. To fix that problem, I run `netstat -n -o'. This way I can find out the process ID that holds the port and kill that app through taskmanager. Now I can restart the service and Hudson comes up fine.

For the last few weeks I had a similar problem. The description says, that it restarts the app, when no processes are running. I missed out on one job that was hold in the build queue and because of a faulty configuration never actually build, therefore preventing Hudson from restarting.

After all of your jobs are finished and your server does not restart. Just visit the restart page again http://server:port/restart and try to restart again. If that doesn't work stop the service and start it again.

---

**UPDATE:**

Since I grew tired of physically logging into the Hudson/Jenkins server, I now use following commands to run the kill remotely. These commands assume that you run the service with a dedicated user (e.g. JenkinsUser). If another process running with the same credentials than the service does and might start java.exe, you need to run the netstat which needs to be executed locally on the Jenkins server or by using rexec (this was not an option for me).

```
:: get the pid of jenkins java.exe
tasklist /S %JENKINSSERVER% /FI "IMAGENAME eq java.exe" /FI "USERNAME eq %DOMAIN\USERNAME%"

:: terminate process use pid from previous command (instead of 1234)
taskkill /S %JENKINSSERVER% /F /T /PID 1234

:: stop the Jenkins service (just in case the service is hanging)
sc \\%JENKINSSERVER% stop Jenkins

:: start the Jenkins service again
sc \\%JENKINSSERVER% start Jenkins
```

If I have to much time, I might create a script out of it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Peter! I'm going to run he update at the end of the day and I'll give it a go if it hangs.

Comment: Amazingly, since asking this question, I've updated Hudson and its plugins and not had an issue with the restart. I can see the logic in what you're saying Peter so will mark your answer as the accepted one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: /restart did not work for me. I got a button to restart and once I clicked it I got the following error. 

udson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Default Windows lifecycle does not support restart.
 at hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle$1.verifyRestartable(Lifecycle.java:83)

I did not install Hudson as a Windows service since that was not an option under Manage Hudson. I'm running version 1.3.98 on my local Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I am not sure if the restart works if you don't run as a service under Windows.

Comment: how do I restart if I just have admin access to the portal and not the actual box (AIX) where it is installed (as a webapp on Tomcat) and `jenkins/restart` gives me the same error as @CACuzcatlan

Comment: How can I Start/Stop/Restart Jenkins on Windows through console?

Comment: @PulakAgrawal: Ask your friendly AIX Admin to do it for you. Sorry, no better answer.

Comment: @RiponAlWasim: Assuming you have it installed as a service. See script above. You need Windows Administrator rights to start and stop the service.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze yeah .. **Friendly** AIX admin with a big company's red tape (Business reason, SR ticket, approval, cost, CAB and 7 days of wait)

Comment: @Peter Schuetze: I'm talking about Jenkins service (previously known as Hudson). Yes, it needs Windows Administrator right to start, stop and restart the service

Answer (score 1):

If the Slave node has the `slave.jar` used as a windows service, that service is defined as "Automatic".
It means it will try to contact the master periodically if the connection has been severed.

You shouldn't click on anything on the server side (in the Node definition) to restart said Node: it should be back online automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer VonC. I'm not actually running any slaves. Just hudson as a master. So do you have any ideas why it hangs when I click the restart button?

Comment: @Toggo: oh ok. Peter's answer might be more relevant then.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed Jenkins on a TomCat server, one alternative solution is to simply restart your Apache TomCat service.